# Spring boot AzureAD AADAuthenticationFilter checks for invalid issuer how do I overwrite or config this to different issuer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, azure-active-directory, netflix-zuul

Using azure ad spring starter 2.1.6. with the AADAuthenticationFilter https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot, the code goes to buildUserPrincipal within this there is a verify issuer call. The default appears below. My issuer is https://login.microsoftonline.com/uuid/v2.0 not the default thus it throws an error, how can I overwrite or config this to check against my issuer?

```
private ConfigurableJWTProcessor<SecurityContext> getAadJwtTokenValidator(JWSAlgorithm jwsAlgorithm) {
    final ConfigurableJWTProcessor<SecurityContext> jwtProcessor = new DefaultJWTProcessor<>();

    final JWSKeySelector<SecurityContext> keySelector =
            new JWSVerificationKeySelector<>(jwsAlgorithm, keySource);
    jwtProcessor.setJWSKeySelector(keySelector);

    jwtProcessor.setJWTClaimsSetVerifier(new DefaultJWTClaimsVerifier<SecurityContext>() {
        @Override
        public void verify(JWTClaimsSet claimsSet, SecurityContext ctx) throws BadJWTException {
            super.verify(claimsSet, ctx);
            final String issuer = claimsSet.getIssuer();
            if (issuer == null || !issuer.contains("https://sts.windows.net/")
                    && !issuer.contains("https://sts.chinacloudapi.cn/")) {
                throw new BadJWTException("Invalid token issuer");
            }
        }
    });
    return jwtProcessor;
}
```